# Is there a way to use a variable label as part of a title in a function in R?

Tags: r, function, title

Is there a way to use a variable label as part of a title in a function in R?

```
print_title <- function(var) {

   cp <- ggcorr(df[2:5], label=TRUE, `label_alpha=TRUE)
   print(cp + ggtitle("Correlation of" label(var)))
}
```

I would like the title of the output to read 'Correlation of Age' where Age is the label of the variable, but this code is not working for me.

Comment: simply use `paste0("Correlation of",label(var))`

Comment: Please provide complete examples that others can  easily run by copying and pasting from your question.  This should include all `library` statements and inputs shown using `dput` as per the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: I have added the paste0, but still no luck.                              
 print_title <- function(var) {
+ library(GGally)
+ cp<-ggcorr(corr1_wk[2:5], label=TRUE, label_alpha=TRUE)
+ print(cp + ggtitle(paste0("Correlation of", label(var))))
+ }                                                   print_title(df$age)

Comment: @SarahSloan This is not entirely clear. I would recommend instead of putting code in your comment, edit your original question and clarify what you have tried. If you want to add a title to your correlation plot you could try this: `print_title <- function(var) { ggcorr(df[2:5], label = TRUE, label_alpha = TRUE) + labs(title = var)
}` ...your function will return a plot with the title based on `var` (no need for `cp` or `paste`). Let me know if this helps.